# How to adjust ContainerTemplate in Jenkinsfile to get Images from private registry

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, containers

I want to get a Docker-Image from my private-docker-registry. I can not find a good solution to describe a authentication in the Jenkinsfile. What do I need to add in the Jenkinsfile to get my Image "my-private-registry.image-name:tag"?

```
pipeline {
agent {
  kubernetes {
    label "${jenkins_slave_id}"
    defaultContainer 'jnlp'
    serviceAccount 'jenkins'
    yaml """
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Pod
        spec:
          restartPolicy: Never
          containers:
            - name: "my-private-container"
              image: "my-private-registry.image-name:tag"
              tty: true
              command:
                - cat
              volumeMounts:
                - name: docker-socket
                  mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
            - name: "jnlp"
```

---

```
stages {
  stage("Do something") {
    steps {
      script {
        container('my-private-container') {
          script {
           //Do something
          }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The authentication settings are in the `Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes and Clouds -> Configure Clouds -> Add a new cloud -> Kubernetes`

Comment: Hi, Thanks, this is already done. Kubernetes is already configured and can download and start Container from Docker-Hub. 
Do I need to add in the Cloud-Configuration my-docker-Image from my private registry?

Comment: Ah sorry I see your question.  Give me a bit let me try to connect to ECR on my install and see

Comment: Have you tried using imagePullSecrets attribute in your yaml template?

Comment: Could you try to configure everything in Kubernetes from scratch and see if is working - check [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/). Please let know the results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have added my imagePullSecret like this:

```
       - name: "my-private-container"
          image: "my-private-registry.image-name:tag"
          imagePullSecrets: ['Docker-Registry']
          tty: true
          command:
            - cat
          volumeMounts:
            - name: docker-socket
              mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
```

I configured my imagePullSecrets in the secrets as "Username and Password".
When I try to run it I get following message:

```
Failed to pull image "my-private-registry.image-name:tag": unknown: Authentication is required
```

Comment: And Docker-Registry is a secret that actually exists in kubernetes and it's associated with the correct registry url?

Comment: What for spedific Credential do I need? I used "Username and Password". Yes the Credentlias are otherwise correct. "docker login my-private-regsitry" is working on my computer.

Comment: Wait are you talking about Jenkin's Credential Manager?  That is not the secret this is referring to.  This is referring to a secret in Kubernetes, not a secret in Jenkins.  `kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=https://ecr.aws.com/myreg --docker-username=test --docker-password=pass`.  It sounds like you're creating a Jenkins secret which is incorrect

Comment: See if you get a response from `kubectl get secret Docker-Registry--output=yaml`

Comment: Thats somehow also not working. I get still the same error. Itried it with namespace, without namespace, with https:// etc..

Comment: When you run `kubectl get secret Docker-Registry--output=yaml` ( dont modify it at all, run this exatly ) do you get a response that shows the secret?

Comment: The response from 'kubectl get secret Docker-Registry --output=yaml' is working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239055/discussion-between-chris-maggiulli-and-greenjenks).

Answer (score 0):

All you need to create cluster object secret with your private registry credentials and then add the secret name in your Pod template as below:

> kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred
> --docker-server=YOUR-PRIVATE-REGISTRY --docker-username=USER --docker-password=PASSWORD

```
pipeline {
agent {
  kubernetes {
    label "${jenkins_slave_id}"
    defaultContainer 'jnlp'
    serviceAccount 'jenkins'
    yaml """
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Pod
        spec:
          imagePullSecrets:
          - name: regcred
          restartPolicy: Never
          containers:
            - name: "my-private-container"
              image: "my-private-registry.image-name:tag"
              tty: true
              command:
                - cat
              volumeMounts:
                - name: docker-socket
                  mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
            - name: "jnlp"
```